# cannot display time selector correctly?

Tags: asp.net

time selector when i add it to my form and add script manager it showed correctly and no error, but in display the time selector button i found it in another place  not coordinate with time selector box until i add this code to html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

it worked , my question is when i add web user control and add time selector in it and add this web user control to web form with master page  the time selector not show correctly the buttons show in place and time selector in another place in web form [image]

Comment: It really unclear what You're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error in Html Default Master Page this error was change shape design